# Resolving Microsoft.Extensions.Logging in an Azure function

Tags: logging, azure-functions

In an Azure function, I'm registering a logger like this:

```
builder.Services
    .AddLogging(config => config.AddApplicationInsights())
```

I'm then resolving it inside a function like this:

```
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 * 1 * * *")]TimerInfo timer, ILogger log)
```

This works fine. The logger is resolved and logs. However, I then have a class that I also register as a transient in the startup, and that class has a logger injected like this:

```
 public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger)
 {
     _logger = logger;
 }
```

My problem is that when I call a method from `MyService` I don't get the log output. It appears that it *is* resolving (I tried changing various things so that it wouldn't, and I get an error message indicating that it hasn't resolved), however, I get no output.

Am I doing something wrong with the registration here?

Comment: Why would you need `ILogger<MyService>` you can just use `Ilogger log` right

Comment: Apparently not - when I do that, I get a null reference exception

Comment: Can you show me your `local.settings.json`

Comment: There is nothing relating to logging in the local.settings.json file.  Should there be?

Answer (score 0):

After scrubbing through some github posts, it looks like it can be done like this.

```
 private readonly ILogger _logger;
 public MyService(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
 {
     _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyService>();
 }
 DoSomething()
 {
  //Use _logger to log info
 }
```

And you should also ensure your service is registered in the `Startup` as well like this
`builder.Services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();`

Comment: To be clear - you're saying that, rather than injecting the logger, you inject the logger factory?

Comment: Yes @CuriousDev please try the above it should work

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any difference